# What is the more efficient way of loading data to db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I must say that i currently use fixtures to populate my database. In an app i'm making, i will need to pre-populate the database with lots of data. I find that fixtures are a very nice way to describe this data, but there are some efficiency problems.

One important problem is managing the big yaml files. I think that it can get a bit overwhelming when i will have like 200 entries there.

Then, using something like Factories is not really to my liking, because it kinda messes data with code and i just want data representation to be available for easy changes.

Thus, i think of writing a small program to convert from csv to yaml and vice versa, in order to manage my entries through excel (i know that such a script exists already).

Do you know of another better way to do this sort of managing ? Notice that my data is not relevant with each other, meaning that a collection.each to populate is out of the question. Each entry is truly individual with lots of different attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all code you want directly in your db/seed.rb file. Inside you can add all script you want.

You can load a YAML file and save the return of this YAML or you can add your object in format you want.

After you just need call the rake task `rake db:seed` to launch this task

Comment: But how would you manage the long series of entries ? Is a conversion to csv a good idea you think ? (for human editing)